# Почему Telebot не видит атрибут «KeyboardButton» для запроса координат пользователя?

Tags: python, синтаксис, telegram, telegram-bot

Собственно код. По сценарию бот делает кнопку, по клику на которую юзер делится своими координатами.

```python
@bot.message_handler(commands=['location']) #Запрос локации
def request_location(message):
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1, resize_keyboard=True)
    button_geo = types.KeyboardButton(text="Отправить местоположение", request_location=True)
    keyboard.add(button_geo)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Поделись местоположением", reply_markup=keyboard)
bot.polling()
```

После запуска команды **/location** вылетает ошибка "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'KeyboardButton'", хотя в документации такой атрибут есть: [Ссылка на документацию](https://tlgrm.ru/docs/bots/api#keyboardbutton)

*Ошибка кроется где то в коде на месте "types.KeyboardButton".*

Answer (score 0):

Подозреваю, что проблема кроется в секции с вашими импортами. Вот мой рабочий вариант:

```
import config
from telebot import TeleBot, types

bot = TeleBot(config.TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['location']) #Запрос локации
def request_location(message):
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1,      resize_keyboard=True)
    button_geo = types.KeyboardButton(text="Отправить местоположение", request_location=True)
    keyboard.add(button_geo)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Поделись местоположением", reply_markup=keyboard)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bot.polling()
```

Comment: Проблема решилась полным удалением и переустановкой пакета Pytelegrambotapi.

Answer (score -1):

Синтаксис был 100% правильный. Проблема была в установке пакета Pytelegrambotapi.

Проблема решилась удалением и переустановкой пакета.